# Omnet++ Interface with Aurdino sensor node

Tags: omnet++

I am doing a project on Wsn Security, where I am having a physical sensor node and would like to connect it to Omnet++ through INET framework with the transferred data being encrypted. I am having a doubt on interfacing between the real sensor node and Omnet++. Can somebody explain in detail about how to interface a physical sensor node to a Omnet++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Unforunalty there is NO easy way to do it. No click and click and it will work.

But there are a possible, in OMNeT++ and in OMNeT++ INET Framework are some Implementation called cRealTimeScheduler. This defines a new Scheduler for OMNeT.

One example is connecting a socket from your pc via Port into OMNeT and a Simulated Webserver will run.

The other example is more complex and work with pcap capturing on device level and is not that what you want.

Choose the implementation with socket communication, check how it works,
remove not needed things.

But there must be sth Brigde: Arduino has several possiblities to connect to a pc... see serial interface and so or network cable ...

The Brigde to the work, it moves Data via socket into Simulator.
Or you do it with writing into a file and reading from that file or other terrible things. 
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:plugin-exts:scheduler

In my master-thesis @university I have done kind off that things allready and 
it works for "my sensor-node". With the realtimeconfiguration and the brigde rewriting all the stuff.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Well I have an Aurdino UNO with a wifi shield.  Now I am going to connect any 2 sensors with this Aurdino Wifi shield and then going to try  sending the data from the sensor through wifi shield to Omnet++ wifi module securely. How about this possibility?

Comment: That is what i mentioned. ... wifi shield communicate via IEEE 802.11 sththing. wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN

You have to forward your data after receiving them from the arduino UNO.
Go there http://www.arduino.org/forums/uno/arduinowifi-library-729#p3066 the know the stuff much better.

Comment: Thanks again. So now ,I have connected my Wifi shield with aurdino UNO and started testing with example commands given in the aurdino IDE. Next, I need to connect a temperature sensor and make it send the data through wifi shield to the simulator i am trying to simulate. Any hints for conection of temperature sensor + aurdino wifi shield + aurdino UNO to internet?

Comment: I have successfully created a physical node and through arduino wifi shield I am sending the data to browser and I am collecting this details in a file with AES encrpyion and interfacing with Omnet++ simulator. But in Simulator I am unable to get back the plain text ( decryption). Can somebody help me in this ?